# How call an API in PHP using Curl with POST parameters

Tags: curl, php-curl

I have a problem attempting to call an API using cURL.
From the API's website console everything works.

cURL:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "accLevelIds": "402881ef74c626680174c761f9f0000b", \ 
   "pin": "7738" \ 
}' 'http://greatfitness.ddns.net:8098/api/person/add'
```

Request URL:

```
http://greatfitness.ddns.net:8098/api/person/add
```

Response body:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "success",
  "data": null
}
```

Response headers:

```
{
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "date": "Mon, 28 Sep 2020 12:43:51 GMT",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "x-xss-protection": "1"
}
```

However when I tried to do the same thing with PHP and cURL I have problems...

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://greatfitness.ddns.net:8098/api/person/add?pin=7737&accLevelIds=402881ef74c626680174c761f9f0000b",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Cookie: JSESSIONID=88F29FD89B315BF85E86297398DF899C"
    ),
));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
if (curl_error($curl)) {
    die('error:' . curl_error($curl));
}
    
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Response:

```
{"ret":"400","msg":"The operation failed!","data":null,"i18nArgs":null,"success":false}
```

I know I'm missing something... but I don't know what!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

$payload = json_encode( array( "pin" => "7737", "accLevelIds" => "402881ef74c626680174c761f9f0000b" ) );

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://greatfitness.ddns.net:8098/api/person/add",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Cookie: JSESSIONID=88F29FD89B315BF85E86297398DF899C"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't works for me... now, I have a 403 Forbidden error. I installed Fiddler, but I don't know where is the problem.